# How to start developping with TypeScript and NodeJS in VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I used to develop web sites with C# or Javascript with Visual Studio and IIS.

I've decided to upgrade to newer tools and try to create a simple web site with VSCode, NodeJS and TypeScript that I'll deploy to Azure later but each time I try a new sample, I get lost as I have the feeling it doesn't do what I want.

I created a TSConfig.json file with this minimum, I understood it creates a "project" in TypeScript:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

A simple main.ts file:

```
class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World');
            return 0;
        }
}
Startup.main();
```

A simpliest index.html file that references the generated main.js file

I wanted to 
    - compile my web site using "$tsc-watch" to benefit from that automatic recompile
    - launch the web site in NodeJS
    - Open the web page in Chrome and being able to debug

But I am wondering, is it the right approach ?  Should it be a tasks.json file that each time runs "$tsc-watch", launch the web site in Node and opens Chrome ?

I started with this tasks.json file :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc-watch"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Chrome",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "chrome.exe",
            "windows": {
                "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
            },
            "args": ["./index.htm"],
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

Then, VSCode created a launch.json file but I'm not sure why and where it fits in the picture:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Would you be able to help me understand what I am doing wrong here and what I need to simply debug my application in VSCode as I would pressing F5 in VSStudio.

Thank you for any help,

Claude

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create the entire build-chain and configuration yourself. I recommend starting with a tool that handles the initial bootstrapping for you. For exampe, use the vue-cli tool to bootstrap a vue.js project with TypeScript. While it may include a little bit of spin-up in understanding vue.js, the vue-cli tool lets you select options (e.g. TypeScript) and auto-generates a project for you. Then, just open the newly created folder in Visual Studio Code and start playing around.

Once you get a feel for how it all ties together, you can add VSCode specific tasks, start modifying configurations, etc.

There are a number of good tutorials on vue.js and, in practice, you'll probably want to leverage a front-end framework when building any real application anyway.

See the following links for tutorials and more information:

[vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/https://)

[vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started)

Comment: Thank you.  This is interesting but the project is a one that I already started in Javascript that I want to rewrite in TypeScript, I plan to use the JSViews framework that looks a lot like vue and other libraries like mapster...  I'll keep searching a bit how to write good launch files and otherwise I'll have a look at vue.